# Using IF/CASE conditioning in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question regarding how you use the IF statement in SQL, so I have 3 tables

- user
- mechanics
- exchanges

The fields in each of tables are as follows

```
 user        mechanics      exchanges
------      ----------      ---------
name         name           id_user
id_user      id_mecha       id_mecha 
                            message
```

I want to use a condition like the following one in which I am going to select the name of the `user` or the `mechanic` with their corresponding `message` if their `id` matches the one that `exchanges` has for each one of them (`user` or `mechanic`)

```
SELECT CASE  
         WHEN mechanics.id_mecha = exchanges.id_mecha  
            THEN  mechanics.name, exchanges.message
         WHEN users.id_user = exchanges.id_user 
            THEN users.name, exchanges.message
FROM users 
JOIN mechanics 
JOIN exchanges
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The double `JOIN` will produce a full cross product between the mechanics and users. This is probably not what you want. You should use a single join with each table, and then combine them with `UNION`.

```
SELECT m.name, e.message
FROM mechanics AS m
JOIN exchanges AS e ON m.id_mecha = e.id_mecha

UNION

SELECT u.name, e.message
FROM users AS u
JOIN exchanges AS e ON m.id_user = e.id_user
```

Comment: You were right, I didn't want a full cross product between mechanics and users, so the UNION worked fine for me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need to `END` the [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) in `SELECT` and you need to have `ON` for `JOIN` like below

```
SELECT CASE  
         WHEN mechanics.id_mecha = exchanges.id_mecha  THEN  mechanics.name
         WHEN users.id_user = exchanges.id_user THEN users.name 
       END,
       exchanges.message
FROM  users u
JOIN mechanics m ON users.id_user = exchanges.id_user
JOIN exchanges e ON mechanics.id_mecha = exchanges.id_mecha
```

Answer (score 0):

in fact you need a `JOIN` with `case` statement (assuming an specific message can be only for a user or for a specific mechanic- not for both at the same time in one row):

```
SELECT case 
       when e.id_user is null then m.name
       when e.id_mecha is null then u.name
       else null end,
       e.message
from exchanges e join users u on e.id_user=u.id_user
     join mechanics m on e.id_mecha=m.id_mecha
```

Comment: You're missing the `END` keyword for `CASE`.

Comment: @Barmar, oh yeah, sorry for it and thanks for your comment. answer edited.